# Azure get SQL DB servers REST request returned "HTTP error 500 : Internal Server Error"

Tags: rest, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I tried using "enumerating servers" Get Servers option in REST API.

I am getting a response "HTTP error 500 : Internal Server Error" .

https://management.database.windows.net:8443/<'SunscriptionID'>/servers

x-ms-version=1.0.

Please help me !

Comment: if that's the URI, then you're missing your subscription id, which should be the segment right after the host/port

Comment: @Jim , I am having subscription ID on my request. Somehow it got missed out here while posting my query in this forum. Still facing the same issue. Any thoughts !?

Comment: @AnandSrinivasan Same as I said to you yesterday, I have the same error since Friday (23rd Nov) the same code was working fine for months; I have submitted a ticked. Here is someone with the same issue: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MOCP/thread/6199108f-5556-4e23-b2d3-85c4d7993861/

Comment: @AnandSrinivasan - My service is working again, can you check your code now?

Comment: @JimO'Neil , its working now ..thanks a ton. Need ur help once again, any idea about getting list of databases inside a server in azure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to an issue from azure DB portal itself. Please find the response from azure support team.

"There was an issue with SQL azure management REST API in all the data centers. This issue has been resolved now.

The Azure service dashboard has been updated : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

Response from support.".